# Boost shared_ptr vector member access

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I am fairly new to boost c++ library and I have a following question.

I have the following snippet of the code in my program.

```
typedef std::vector<int> Indices;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Indices> IndicesPtr;
...
IndicesPtr indices (new Indices);
```

After I add the data to **indices** and later I want to access individual members using operator [] I get an error message.

Error: error: no match for operator[] in indices[i]. I fail to understand why does this happen. Is there specific ways to access when using boost::shared_ptr<>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `shared_ptr` here, use just `vector`, but if you want (for example for training) you can use

```
indices->operator[](index)
```

or dereference `shared_ptr`

```
(*indices)[index]
```

just as raw pointer.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful . Is using shared_ptr with vector is not efficient? And also can we update vector like for eg. indices->operator[](index) = 5?

Comment: @kcc__ yes, you can. I just don't see the point to use `shared_ptr` on vector, especially here. vector is dynamic array, why you should use shared pointer on dynamic array?

Comment: I see, however I thought that boost::shared_ptr<> is better when using for allocating memory. Nevertheless perhaps I understood wrongly. So where does the use of shared_ptr makes more sense if you can just give me an example or two.

Comment: @kcc__ use shared/scoped pointer, instead raw pointer. scoped, or shared depends on task. And BTW, there are many articles about smart pointer usage.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because boost::shared_ptr does not have operator[], std::vector does. If you want to access the vector's [] operator, you have to dereference the shared pointer:

```
(*indices)[index]
```

If you used the classic pointer (*), you would still run into similar problem, but in C++ pointer[] treats it as an array (even if the pointer is not an array) which in most cases would result in a segmentation fault (when accessing any cell different than 0)